# In what conditon, Kronecker product returns linearly independent vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, kronecker-product

Consider two "set" of vectors ${\mathcal A} = \{\alpha_i \in {\mathbb R}^n\colon i = 1,\ldots,mn\}$ and ${\mathcal B} = \{\beta_i \in {\mathbb R}^m\colon i = 1,\ldots,mn\}$, where term "set" means its elements can be duplicate. Let $\gamma_i = \alpha_i \bigotimes \beta_i$, where $\bigotimes$ is the Kronecker product, and $\Gamma = \{\gamma_i  = \alpha_i \bigotimes \beta_i\colon i = 1,\ldots,mn\}$.

Then, can we judge the linear dependence of $\Gamma$ by ${\mathcal A}$ and ${\mathcal B}$?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of condition do you expect? The vectors $A$ and $B$ are linearly dependent anyway if $n\ne1$ and $m\ne1$.

Comment: @daw Thanks for your comments. If ${\mathcal A} = \{\alpha_i\colon i = 1,\ldots,n\}$ and ${\mathcal B} = \{\beta_j\colon j = 1,\ldots,m\}$, then the statement you give is correct. In that case, linearly independent ${\mathcal A}$ and ${\mathcal B}$ can be further proved to be a necessary and sufficient condition. Yet, in this question, ${\mathcal A}$ have $mn$ elements, so as ${\mathcal B}$. The proof seems to be hard due to the loss of symmetry in choosing $\alpha$ and $\beta$.